# Unsupervised De-Dupe Rule failing in 5.9.0

Tags: contacts, duplicate-contacts

Since upgrading to 5.9.0 (Drupal 7.6), we have noticed that all self-service / online event registrations are creating duplicate contacts - of both the individual end the organization (employer) record.

Having looked at the Unsupervised rule, it should absolutely be triggering - eg there are multiple contacts that have been created where the first name, last name, and email all exactly match an existing contact.

Our individual unsupervised rule is:

[image: Screenshot of unsupervised de-dupe rule]

Has anyone else seen this behaviour on their installation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/28062/unsupervised-reserved-rule-for-individuals-not-working ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if its somehow related to one of the regression for 5.9.0 for Anonymous user ACL permission which is fixed in 5.9.1. Would be worth trying after upgrading CiviCRM to 5.9.1 or applying patch from [here](https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/13467.patch)!

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Thanks! I've updated to 5.9.1 and will report back

Comment: Sure let us know if it fixed your issue!

Comment: Hi Pradeep, just been able to check (sorry for the delay) and the problem appears solved. Thank you!